Single pole light switch changing to smart switch
I have a single pole flip switch connected to my pool light. It runs from a gfci switch that trips incase of any water issues in the light housing. I have a hot wire neutral and ground connected to my flip switch and it works fine. I am trying to change it to a single pole smart light switch that has a line neutral load and ground. I connected it and left the load unconnected and it does not work. Should I have connected the load wire to something?

White wire does not mean neutral.  If you do not have two or more white wires connected together in back of the switch box, then no neutral, which a smart switch wants.


I have a hot wire neutral and ground connected to my flip switch and it works fine.

No, you do not. You have a black wire, a white wire and a bare ground. Repeat after me, write on the chalkboard 100 times, etc.:
Neutral is always white, but white is not always neutral!
A standard toggle switch needs two active wires (i.e., excluding ground). Historically, there have been two ways to wire up such a switch:

Panel -> Switch -> Light

In this case, black is hot from panel to switch and switched hot from switch to light. White is neutral the whole way through, with the two white wires connected together in the switch box but not actually connected to the switch.
To replace an ordinary switch with a smart switch, timer, etc. that requires neutral, you would connect the neutral for the switch to the existing two neutrals that are already in the box.

Panel -> Light -> Switch

In this case, black is hot from panel to light box but does not attach to the light fixture in the box. Instead it connects to the white wire going down to the switch (which should be marked with black mark or tape, but often isn't). The black from the switch is switched hot and connects to the light fixture. Neutral is the white wire from the panel to the light fixture, not passing through the switch box.
This particular configuration saves a wire and, in particular, allows everything except 3-way switches (two switches that control one light) to be wired with black/white cable instead of needing black/white/red cable.
This configuration is not allowed in new installations because now neutral is required in switch boxes to make connecting smart switches easier.
This configuration sounds like what you have and, if so, it will NOT work for you unless you can find an appropriate smart switch that does not require neutral. The alternative is to run a new black/white/red cable from the light fixture to the switch with black as hot, red as switched hot and white as - you guessed it - neutral.

It depends on your smart switch. Consult with manual. Some switches require live and neutral, some can work only either live or neutral and load.
Protective earth (ground) is not for power delivery and therefore irrelevant for anything but protection. If you connected the switch to live and protective earth only, it is not being powered via the load and is therefore not operation. It is as if you only have one wire connected to it. Example below excludes protective earth entirely (the switch is not grounded).
Example of a random smart switch:



While the last sentence is accurate, it is very dangerous to switch neutral.  It leaves hot live and able to knock someone six feet under if they believe it is dead.  One reason to never trust switches and use the breaker to turn off the power.

@crip659 is correct. To clarify: From the perspective of providing power for the switch's internal operations, line and neutral can be interchanged. However, since the "line" will also be passed through/switched as "load", line vs. neutral must be correct for safety of the load device (e.g., light or fan) wiring.

Improved the text, thank you. Interchangeability is now not discussed. Regarding danger, it is not safe to mess with electrical without proper knowledge. It is not safe to assume that if one pole switch is off, circuit is not live regardless of how it is connected.
